# Using OPENROWSET in an INSERT statement while specifying the values of another column?

Tags: sql, insert, openrowset

I'm using OPENROWSET(BULK ...) to insert the contents of a file into my table.  The problem is that I also need to specify the value of another column in the same INSERT statement.

I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\foo.bin', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

I'm sure there's a way to also specify the value of a different column here, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it, it was in the link posted by astandar, but under example D:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (col1, col2)
SELECT 'foo' AS col1, *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\foo.bin', SINGLE_BLOB) AS col2
```